# Python ord() equivalent in NumPy

Tags: numpy

In Python, to get the ASCII value of a character we can do:

```
>>> x = ord('k')
>>> x
107
```

What is the equivalent Python "ord" method in NumPy? I see some solutions say to do hacks like list comprehension before passing it NumPy. However, I want a NumPy method to do the conversion. It seems there is not a way. Is there? Again, I don't want list comprehension, map, or lambda or other work-arounds. Those are all Python methods. I'm looking for the equivalent NumPy function.

EDIT: Based on Hilbert's comment, I want to convert NumPy array "x" to the ASCII equivalent using vectorized operations:

```
>>> a = ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
>>> x = np.array(a)
>>> x
array(['g', 'h', 'i', 'j'], dtype='<U1')
>>>
```

So if "y" were my final array (after the conversion) it would look like this:

```
>>> y
array([103, 104, 105, 106])
>>> type(y)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>>
```

Comment: NumPy is a Python library, so you can just use the Python builtin... I don't really get the question.

Comment: Are you using `np.chararray` or an array of Python strings? Can you give an example of an array in question may look like?

Comment: I don't want use any looping. I want to use vectorized type of operation. I graduated from a data science program. And the prof said never to use loops in vectorized frameworks (or any variants of iteration).

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem based on your question, I clarified an example with a NumPy array with some characters that I want converted to its ASCII equivalent using a vectorized operation.

Comment: `.tobytes()` may be helpful.

Comment: To elaborate on suggestion by @9769953, you could use `np.frombuffer(x.tobytes(), dtype=np.int32)` in this case.

Comment: Ok, let me check tobytes() and frombuffer...

Comment: Of course, under the hood, this still uses a loop (possibly two). A list comprehension may be just as fast; or at least for relatively small arrays, any speed difference will be negligible.

Comment: @9769953 To be fair, I get around 200x speedup with array of size 4000. List comprehension seems to be faster for the 4-element array in the example.

Comment: Holy Cow! It works! I spent hours with the NumPy docs and there are no examples. Honestly, I would think an ord equivalent in NumPy is in order. If either of you wants to add the answer, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: There is also `x.view(np.int32))` which gives `array([103, 104, 105, 106], dtype=int32)`

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I think you should post this as an answer.

Comment: Yes, that works too. @JoachimIsaksson

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[numpy.ndarray.view](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) returns a view of the same array with another (equally sized) datatype, and should due to not copying anything pretty much be instantaneous.

```
>>> x = np.array(['g', 'h', 'i', 'j'])
>>> x
array(['g', 'h', 'i', 'j'], dtype='<U1')
>>> y = x.view(np.int32)
>>> y
array([103, 104, 105, 106], dtype=int32)
```

Being a view to the original data though, if you mutate the original array, be aware that you also mutate the view.

```
>>> x[2]='x'
>>> y
array([103, 104, 120, 106], dtype=int32)
```